# can not upload image using PUT method

Tags: php, api, image-uploading

I want to ask, before I make a rest api for image upload function with POST method it works, but fitting when I want to try to make the update function by using PUT method it failed.
the response is always empty picture continues.
which I want to ask if the PUT method is different perlakuaanya?
I use $ _FILES ["image"] to capture the upload data.
is it wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [PHP official document of $_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) is clear:

> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the
>   **HTTP POST method**. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST
>   method uploads section.

`$_FILES` only accepts "POST" method, so you can't use it to fetch files via HTTP PUT.

For getting files from "PUT" method, you should use `php://input` stream, please refer to [PUT method support](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php), here is an example from official:

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```